# SQLite database image getting malformed at build time in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm working on a iOS 6 app, and am using a SQLite database to store data. At startup the app does a select on the database and displays the results on the first screen.
However I've started to get an "Database disk image is malformed" error when trying to run the select.

The strange thing is that I can use SQLite browser, http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/,  to do the select on the database in the project folder. But if I try to open the database after it has been copied to the simulator folder, /Users//Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhone simulator/6.0/Applications/... then I get a disk image is malformed.

The database is not being accessed by a background thread, nor am I using breakpoints to halt execution as is being suggested as a reason here [sqlite database disk image malformed on iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934641/sqlite-database-disk-image-malformed-on-iphone-sdk).

No more than one execution being done on the database at once.

All hints, tips and possible solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that this had something to do with me bundling a rather large database file with the app (larger than 3 GB). I've fixed the problem by doing a in-app download of the data over wifi. This caused the database error to fade away.