# Mac Application using SQLite database has three databases created in 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: objective-c, macos, sqlite, core-data, osx-mavericks

I have a Mac application that is using sqlite as it's database. On OSX 10.7 and 10.8 when the application is launched it creates one file as it's database storage: **appName.sqlite**

After upgrading to **10.9 Mavericks** I noticed that when I launch my application, it now creates three files.

- appName.sqlite
- appName.sqlite-shm
- appName.sqlite-wal

I am assuming they are some kind of temporary files, but I cannot open any of them. As far as I understand with 10.9 Mavericks, SQLite has been updated, I'm wondering if this behavior is related.

Any insight would be extremely helpful.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the .db-shm and .db-wal extensions in Sqlite databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778723/what-are-the-db-shm-and-db-wal-extensions-in-sqlite-databases)

Comment: Yes the latter two are files created by SQLite.  The one is a Write Ahead Log (changed behaviour from older versions of SQLite). You can disable this by setting the persistentStore options of journal_mode=DELETE.  The other is used by the driver for managing access to shared memory.  Read more at www.sqlite.org.  For the most part just ignore them or if the are potentially confusing for the users then revert to the old journal mode.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, your answer led me to this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DataManagement/WhatsNew_CoreData_OSX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duncan's response has put me in the right direction, I have done some more research and it turns out that the answer was right in the release notes...

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DataManagement/WhatsNew_CoreData_OSX/

Mavericks came with the following change to the default SQLite behavior which resulted in my issue...

"The Core Data SQLite persistent store will default to using WAL journal_mode on all applications linked on or after 10.9. This mode offers better reliability and performance than the classic SQLite rollback (delete) journaling. WAL journal_mode is not, however, recommended for read-only database files, or for files that need to interoperate with OS X v10.6 or earlier."