# Why do I need to download whole 'databases' directory in Android to see the contents of SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

So I'm inserting and retrieving data from SQLite database successfully. But if I go to Device File Explorer, save the .db file(from `databases` directory) in my computer and open it with `sqlite3` from terminal(with root access), it shows no tables, no content whatsoever(I also tried SQLiteBrowser and Database Navigator plugin and result's the same).

However, there are `.db-shm` and `.db-wal` files in there too, So if I download the whole directory and then open `.db`, it shows me contents with no problem. So what do these files do, exactly? Are they any kind of metadata? Why do I need to download them every time, too?

*Note: I'm running an emulator.*

***Edit***: For users claiming that this is a duplicate question: I saw that linked question & answer and it didn't make clear what do these files do or why do I need to also download them to see my `.db` file.

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778723/what-are-the-db-shm-and-db-wal-extensions-in-sqlite-databases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the .db-shm and .db-wal extensions in Sqlite databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778723/what-are-the-db-shm-and-db-wal-extensions-in-sqlite-databases)

Comment: Also, instead of taking the hassle of copying .db file from storage and then checking, you can use some cool libraries like : https://github.com/facebook/stetho for database debugging

Comment: The  `-wal` contains data not yet checkpointed (copied back to the database), so you need it, the `-shm` does not contain persistent data, you don't need to copy it

Comment: @AsifRahman Thanks. I'll use Stetho from now on.

Answer (score 1):

From the [source](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)

**-wal**

> Write-Ahead Log (WAL) Files
> A write-ahead log or WAL file is used in place of a rollback journal when SQLite is operating in WAL mode. As with the rollback journal, the purpose of the WAL file is to implement atomic commit and rollback. The WAL file is always located in the same directory as the database file and has the same name as the database file except with the 4 characters "-wal" appended. **The WAL file is created when the first connection to the database is opened and is normally removed when the last connection to the database closes. However, if the last connection does not shutdown cleanly, the WAL file will remain in the filesystem and will be automatically cleaned up the next time the database is opened.**

**-shm**

> Shared-Memory Files
> When operating in WAL mode, all SQLite database connections associated with the same database file need to share some memory that is used as an index for the WAL file. In most implementations, this shared memory is implemented by calling mmap() on a file created for this sole purpose: the shared-memory file. The shared-memory file, if it exists, is located in the same directory as the database file and has the same name as the database file except with the 4 characters "-shm" appended. Shared memory files only exist while running in WAL mode.
>
> The shared-memory file contains no persistent content. The only
> purpose of the shared-memory file is to provide a block of shared
> memory for use by multiple processes all accessing the same database
> in WAL mode. If the VFS is able to provide an alternative method for
> accessing shared memory, then that alternative method might be used
> rather than the shared-memory file. For example, if PRAGMA
> locking_mode is set to EXCLUSIVE (meaning that only one process is
> able to access the database file) then the shared memory will be
> allocated from heap rather than out of the shared-memory file, and the
> shared-memory file will never be created.
>
> **The shared-memory file has the same lifetime as its associated WAL
> file. The shared-memory file is created when the WAL file is created
> and is deleted when the WAL file is deleted. During WAL file recovery,
> the shared memory file is recreated from scratch based on the contents
> of the WAL file being recovered.**

Hope this will clear things for you.